# freebsd12 can not use clang tool AddressSanitizer to check memory leak?

Tags: clang, freebsd

clang AddressSanitizer how to use ,please see [addressSantitizer](https://releases.llvm.org/10.0.0/tools/clang/docs/AddressSanitizer.html)

```c
// simple test memory code, test.c
// how to compile,
// cc -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g -O1 test.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *p = (char *)malloc(100);
    memset(p, 0, 100);
    p[0]='f';
    p[1]='x';
    printf("%s\n", p); 
    return 0;
}
```

I can compile simple c code on freebsd12(clang version 10.0.1), but it run no print about memory leak.

```
[pi@xbsd ~]$ ./a.out 
fx
[pi@xbsd ~]$
```

Linux platform (ubuntu 20.04 gcc 9.3), same code , test can print which line memroy leak, as follow:

```
[devlinux]$ ./a.out 
fx

=================================================================
==27901==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Direct leak of 100 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7fdb7d9ebf18 in __interceptor_malloc ../../.././libsanitizer/asan/asan_malloc_linux.cc:144
    #1 0x400784 in main /home/test/test.c:7
    #2 0x7fdb7d539554 in __libc_start_main (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x22554)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: 100 byte(s) leaked in 1 allocation(s).
```

Comment: iirc, this was a Google created thing that uses the Linux kernel so of course FreeBSD is not the Linux kernel. There is a similar thing in FreeBSD's kernel you can use but I have no information to provide on that.

Answer (score 1):

To detect leaks with you need to run your binary with `ASAN_OPTIONS=detect_leaks=1` in the environment. On FreeBSD that will then give this error:

```
==63559==AddressSanitizer: detect_leaks is not supported on this platform.
```

You can look at setting MALLOC_CONF and having `malloc` do the leak detection. You will probably have to rebuild malloc with `MALLOC_PRODUCTION` set appropriately.